# SQL : AVG of multiple columns and multiplication on distinct dates

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm trying to return all rows and get an average of Weight*Reps as volume while distinct on logdate and exercise_name ordering by logdate where ownerid is in GET and table1='exercises'.  I'm coding in php, odbc connection to access.

Table is as follows:

ID(unique) Weight(number)   Reps(number)  Setname(number)  logdate(date)  Ownerid(number) exercise_name(text) table(text)

I know this is a complex SQL statement so I'm just going to embarrass myself to even attempt this thing.

Any and all help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: What you want isn't 10% clear (at least to me).  Particularly the "where ownerid is in GET" and "table1='exercises'".  It looks like you've phrased your question in pseudo-SQL.  It may be clearer if it was in plain English.  A sample of what the output you're after would look like may be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was really intending to be clear.  'ownerid' is a $_GET from the URL.  I figured programmers like yourselves aren't English experts either, but apparently I was wrong. Looks like HawkEgg understood.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = sprintf('
Select avg(weight*reps), logdate, exercise_name
where owner_id = %d
from table1
order by logdate
group by logdate, exercise_name
', $_GET['ownerid']
);
```

Comment: Thanks HawkEgg, I did a modified version of yours... sprintf("
Select avg(weight*reps) as volume, logdate, exercise_name
from synclogs where ownerid =%d AND table1='exercises'
group by logdate, exercise_name order by logdate
", $_GET['ownerid']
);

Comment: order by has to be at the end and where has to be after from, but other than that.. you got it!  Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd love to give you credit but I dont have 15 rep.  I hope someone reading this will give you a rep up.

Comment: You can't vote for my answer being useful, but I thought you could still mark it as being correct.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your final comment here.  I did mark it as correct and also just marked it as useful.